# Does an upcast lesser restoration count as magical healing of 6th level or higher

Tags: dnd-5e, healing, disease

I'm playing through a published module (not naming to avoid potential spoilers) and I just got attacked by an aboleth's tentacle attack and due to not receiving the whisper from the DM on Roll20 (He whispered the character and not me by mistake so I didn't receive it.) I waited more than a minute before trying to cure the disease. The creature's stat block says for the tentacle attack

> **Tentacle.** Melee Weapon Attack: +9 to hit, reach 10 ft., one target. Hit: 12 (2d6 + 5) bludgeoning damage. If the target is a creature, it must succeed on a DC 14 Constitution saving throw or become diseased. The disease has no effect for 1 minute and can be removed by any magic that cures disease. After 1 minute, the diseased creature's skin becomes translucent and slimy, the creature can't regain hit points unless it is underwater, and the disease *can be removed only by heal or another disease-curing spell of 6th level or higher.* When the creature is outside a body of water, it takes 6 (1d12) acid damage every 10 minutes unless moisture is applied to the skin before 10 minutes have passed.

The important part here is that it specifically requires a "disease-curing spell of 6th level or higher." We got it cured with lesser restoration by retconning the one minute due to the technical issues with Roll20 but this brought up the question of "**does an upcast spell such as Lesser Restoration count as a disease-curing spell of 6th level or higher?**"

Comment: That could be a duplicate yes but also when the DM looked this up he never saw anything for it. I figured I'll either get an answer or someone would link it to another question which gives us the answer and this wording would help other people find it.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate it is just a VERY closely related question.